# Demora na primeria chamada servico WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Estou desenvolvimento uma aplicação utilizando WCF para distribuir, esta tudo funcionando tranquilo, porém tem uma coisa estranha, sempre que utilizo o serviço a primeira vez demora muito,(quase um minuto para uma pesquisa simples no banco de dados), porém se eu realizar uma nova chamada ao serviço fica instantâneo, se eu fechar a aplicação e rodar novamente ai volta a demorar. Alguém qual a melhor forma de resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

A primeira execução geralmente demora mais, porque ao chamar pela primeira vez o WCF o `Channel Factory` é instanciado e preparado para a comunicação e esta operação consome recursos consideráveis. A partir da primeira chamada o `Channel Factory` fica armazenado e as próximas chamadas consomem menos tempo.

O que pode ser feito é avaliar como o serviço esta sendo chamado, se você cria uma instância do serviço a cada chamada ou inicialização do aplicativo, isto irá acabar causando este desconforto. Você pode alterar a forma de chamada do serviço hospedando o mesmo, ou até criando um serviço (do Windows) para instanciar o WCF na inicialização do computador do cliente. Veja este link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43f89088-546b-46b0-adf8-214deb1741bd/how-to-cache-channelfactory?forum=wcf

Nele foi discutido este tipo de problema.